# display a variable with whiptail

Tags: linux, bash, whiptail

I want to display the value of a real-time variable in a whiptail interface.
I my incremented variable like that =

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1

while test $i -ne 51
do 

    echo "$i" 

    i=$(($i + 1)) #icremente i

done
```

how I can display the real-time value in a GUI with whiptail?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way would be to pipe the results to a `--gauge` option (gauge widget).  whiptail's [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail) lists that.

whiptail implements a subset of [dialog's](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) options; if you were using dialog, one might suggest displaying successive `--infobox` messages (also part of the subset), but the effect with xterm may not be good -- too much flashing (dialog cancels the switch to xterm's alternate screen which many terminal descriptions use).

Here is a sample using the latter:

```
#! /bin/sh

: ${PROG=whiptail}

left=10
unit="seconds"
while test $left != 0
do

$PROG --title "INFO BOX" "$@" \
        --infobox "Hi, this is $left $unit to read this..." 10 52
left=`expr $left - 1`
test $left = 1 && unit="second"
sleep 1
done
```

If you were to use that in xterm without disabling the alternate screen switching (e.g., setting the resource `*titeInhibit:false`) it would not work well, of course.